# Error 1443, en mysql, no puedo insertar mas datos a una tabla con un trigger que esta destinado a borrar datos!

Tags: mysql

Quiero realizar un trigger que elimine el registro de una tabla llamada stock al momento que en la tabla cotizacion el campo estatus cambie a 1
tengo el siguiente codigo

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER elimina_maquina BEFORE INSERT ON cotizacion
FOR EACH ROW 
    DELETE a1, a2 FROM cotizacion AS a1 INNER JOIN stock AS a2
    WHERE a1.estatus=1
    AND a1.id_serie=a2.id_serie;
     $$
DELIMITER ;
```

pero el error que me muestra es el del titulo

> MySql Error: Can't update table in stored function/trigger because it
>   is already used by statement which invoked this stored
>   function/trigger

aqui tengo una captura de la relacion de la tabla[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Ya hay una respuesta a una pregunta similar a la tuya. Voy a cerrar esta por duplicado. Revisala, y si no es el mismo problema, aclara porque en la pregunta (usa el boton [edit]) y deja un comentario con mi nombre (@gbianchi) asi la volvemos a abrir

Comment: @gbianchi listo!

Comment: Listo no es el mismo problema? O listo eso lo soluciona?

Comment: no es el mismo problema :(

Comment: Querras decir que no es la misma solucion. El problema es el mismo, no podes modificar la tabla cotizacion dentro de un trigger de cotizacion. Tal vez solo esta mal lo que queres hacer en el trigger? Pq queres borrar el contenido de a1? Pq por la descricion, solo queres borrar el contenido de a2.

Comment: a lo mejor lo tengo mal estructurado :(
solo quiero borrar los datos de la tabla a2 cuando en a1 el campo estatus cambie a 1

Comment: Entonces saca del delete la tabla a1.